# Warning: "The method parameter $context is never used" issue when submitting Magento2 extension to marketplace

Tags: php, magento2

I am getting issue "**The method parameter $context is never used**" in my InstallData.php script when submitting Magento2 extension to marketplace in technical review.

Can Anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: make sure that you are installing the extension the right way, checkout the installations docs for that extension.

Comment: @hasan this is a warning from magento extension review team.
My extension got rejected from magento marketplace.

Comment: @Chauhan Did you get any fix for this? I am also facing this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use following

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart     
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)     
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```